# CSS e JS em produção do NodeJS + ExpressJS + Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, socket.io

Estou com um problema em um chat que utiliza NodeJS + ExpressJS + Socket.IO.
Em ambiente local não acontece problemas. Contudo, quando o ponho em produção estou tendo problemas com CSS's e JS's.
Eu abro a página no Chrome, verifico a aba Network do inspect e vejo que alguns arquivos ficam marcados como pending. Isso não acontece sempre mas está acontecendo com uma boa frequẽncia.
Em outras palavras, as coisas estão demorando para carregar. O que poderia ser isso? As vezes ele vai rapidinho as vezes não.

Eu estou utilizando um servidor dedicado que pode ser visto aqui:
https://www.hostgator.com.br/servidores/planos-de-servidor-dedicado.php
O que tenho aqui é o dedicado standard.

Já tentei fazer coisas básicas no NodeJS e subir para teste e permanece a mesma coisa.

A página de teste é: http://grupicrm.com.br:3000/

Comment: No começo de `index.js` tem `var endereco = "http://192.168.1.100:3000/";`, mas o IP de grupicrm.com.br é 198.1.103.47 - será que tem a ver?

Comment: Desculpe, vou fazer a substituição.

Comment: Parece que o problema era isso mesmo. Vou colocar como resposta.

Comment: Não era não. Ele estava configurado devidamente anteriormente e continuou dando erro.

Answer (score 1):

A requisição está sendo feita para o endereço errado.

No começo de `index.js` tem

```
var endereco = "http://192.168.1.100:3000/";
```

Mas o IP de grupicrm.com.br é 198.1.103.47 - mude para:

```
var endereco = "http://198.1.103.47:3000/";
```

---

Outra coisa: parece que o HostGator não permite sockets, a não ser que você tenha um servidor dedicado e **faça uma solicitação** abrindo um ticket:

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/socket-connections

Veja na tabela, em português (procure Socket Server):

http://faq.hostgator.com.br/content/1/99/pt-br/compatibilidade-e-disponibilidade-de-alguns-servi%C3%A7os-e-tecnologias.html

Comment: @j-bruni esse foi um erro do último commit que realizei esqueci de alterar. Contudo, esse problema de pending dos arquivos já é velho. Receio inclusive que possa ser um problema com o servidor e não com a aplicação.

Comment: Ok. Atualizei a resposta - dê uma olhada. Parece que é o HostGator bloqueando mesmo...

Comment: Pode ser uma possibilidade sim. Estarei entrando em contato com a HostGator e darei um posicionamento aqui. Contudo, eu consigo vizualizar suas conexões no painel. E há informações sendo trocadas. O que implica que os sockets estão abertos, não?

Comment: No painel aqui, apenas a requisição inicial retorna (para `http://grupicrm.com.br:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1395321623072`, ou seja, ainda usando HTTP). Depois, para efetivamente usar o socket, só dá "pending"...

Comment: Eu vi o que você falou. Mas creio que ali fique pending mesmo pois os sockets estão abertos e há troca de informações. Ainda estou esperando uma resposta da HostGator em relação a isso. Porém as vezes esse pending aparece mesmo antes de chegar ao socket.io.